# How to write Junits for ObjectMapper

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am trying to cover My JsonService utility class with Junits but i am getting exception and i am trying to resolve this from long time but still issue not resolved can some one help me please.

### JsonService

```
    public final class JsonService {
        private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER;

private JsonService() {
        // Added to remove sonar issues.
    }

    static {

        log.debug("Start of JsonService static block ");

        MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        log.debug("End of JsonService static block ");
    }

        public static <T> T getObjectFromJson(final Object jsonString, final Class<T> valueType) {

                // log.debug("Start of JsonService.getObjectFromJson() method.. {}");

                T object = null;
                if (jsonString != null) {
                    try {
                        object = MAPPER.readValue(jsonString.toString(), valueType);
                        // log.debug(DEBUG_LOG_STR, object);
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                        log.error(ERROR_LOG_STR + " in method getObjectFromJson(). Exception Message={}, Exception Stack ={}",
                                io.getMessage(), io);
                        throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.JSON_SERIALIZATION_ERROR, io.getCause());
                    }
                }
                // log.debug("End of JsonService.getObjectFromJson() method.. {}");
                return object;
            }
    }
```

### JsonServiceTest

```
 public class JsonServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void getObjectFromJsonTest() throws Exception {
        // PowerMockito.mockStatic(JsonService.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestHelper helper = new TestHelper();
        helper.setName("name");
        helper.setId(1);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(helper);
        TestHelper actual = JsonService.getObjectFromJson(json, TestHelper.class);
        assertEquals(actual.getName(), "name");
        assertEquals(actual.getId(), 1);
    }

    class TestHelper {
        String name;
        long id;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }

}
```

### Exception

```
com.att.idp.externalpartnerorder.exception.ServiceException
    at com.att.idp.externalpartnerorder.common.util.JsonService.getObjectFromJson(JsonService.java:81)
    at com.att.idp.externalpartnerorder.common.util.JsonServiceTest.getObjectFromJsonTest(JsonServiceTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. There are some classes and values, which you haven't defined. Also, your unit test declares what to do when the static method is called with your `PowerMockito.when()` line, but you are not calling the method anywhere after this setup. In fact, your test method just ends. Also see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mock `ObjectMapper` try to convert a object of any class type do you have in the code and convert to JSON using ObjectMapper and call the method `getObjectFromJson` then assert the object properties after that.

> Steps

1. Create helper pojo test class in
2. Convert it to json
3. Call the method and verify the return object

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;

public class JsonServiceTest {

    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final long ID = 1L;

    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Rule
    public RuleChain ruleChain  = RuleChain.outerRule(collector).around(expectedException);

    @Test
    public void getObjectFromJsonTest() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestHelper helper = new TestHelper();
        helper.setName(NAME);
        helper.setId(ID);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(helper);

        // Act
        TestHelper actual = JsonService.getObjectFromJson(json, TestHelper.class);

        // Assert
        collector.checkThat(actual.getName(), equalTo(NAME));
        collector.checkThat(actual.getId(), equalTo(ID));
    }

    @Test
    public void getExceptionFromJsonTest() throws Exception {
        // Assert
        expectedException.expect(Exception.class);

        // Arrange
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestExceptionHelper helper = new TestExceptionHelper();
        helper.setTitle(TITLE);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(helper);

        // Act
        TestExceptionHelper actual = JsonService.getObjectFromJson(json, TestExceptionHelper.class);
    }

    class TestExceptionHelper implements Serializable {
        String title;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    static class TestHelper implements Serializable {
        String name;
        long id;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213535/discussion-on-answer-by-sc0der-how-to-write-junits-for-objectmapper).